# Java can't connect to MySQL if password contain % symbol

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my connection URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://mydbhost:3306/mydatabase?user=username&password=%u16*!ypK@WrUQbr
```

When i call

```
DriverManager.getConnection()
```

with current URL i'm catching exception:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u1"
```

If connection URL not contain % everything works.

i have found some info about this issue, and there recommend to do next conversion :

```
replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25")
```

With this conversion i have error:

```
Access denied for user(incorrect password)
```

Can somebody help to convert url correctly?

Comment: @Berger: This question is not a mere query string parameters type. Because the parameters are passed and parsed by `getConnection` method of implementing `DriverManager`. Problem point must be there. Hence can't be treated as duplicate.

Comment: @RavinderReddy : Oh yes you're right, just removing the flag.

Comment: '@' and '!' are reserved characters and '%' is used to encode reserved characterss.. Have you tried passing user and password apart from URL: `getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`?

Comment: @Berger but one of the answer given there is working! `String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/pwd?user=pwd&password=" + URLEncoder.encode("%u16*!ypK@WrUQbr", "UTF-8");
`

Comment: @RavinderReddy  `java.sql.DriverManager` does no parsing whatsoever, that is up to individual JDBC drivers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: please read _... implementing `DriverManager` ..._ in my comment. The loaded _suitable driver_ implements it.

Comment: @RavinderReddy `DriverManager` is a concrete class in Java, not something that is implemented by a driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: read my comment again. _loaded suitable driver_ ...

Comment: Please read here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/DriverManager.java#620 and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/Driver.java#Driver.connect%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Properties%29

Comment: It is the implementing Driver class that should be parsing and accepting connection url parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it with below string, where all reserved characters in your password are replaced with the appropriate percent-encoded value:

```
% : %25
* : %2A
! : %21
@ : %40

"jdbc:mysql://mydbhost:3306/mydatabase?user=username&password=%25u16%2A%21ypK%40WrUQbr"
```

More information about percent-encoding [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as "Carlos Heuberger" recommended,
call getConnection(String url, String user, String password)

In this style it works, and from my view looks more clear instead of build one huge URL with all parameters included